# In SQLAlchemy, how do I specify a full-text index?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, sqlalchemy

```
class AccountIndexes(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'account_indexes'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False, unique=True, index=True)
    full_name = Column(String(255), nullable=True)
    __table_args__ = {'mysql_engine':'MyISAM'}
```

That's my table. How do I make a "full text index" on full_name? (not a normal index)

Comment: Note: I don't need to actually use the query API. I just need to define it and create the index. (I'm using raw SQL anyway)

Answer (score 1):

If you can check the code in `Index` of `sqlalchemy.schema` then they wrote

```
def __init__(self, name, *columns, **kw):
    """Construct an index object.

    :param name:
      The name of the index

    :param \*columns:
      Columns to include in the index. All columns must belong to the same
      table.

    :param unique:
        Defaults to False: create a unique index.

    :param \**kw:
        Other keyword arguments may be interpreted by specific dialects.

    """
    self.table = None 
    # will call _set_parent() if table-bound column
    # objects are present
    ColumnCollectionMixin.__init__(self, *columns)
    self.name = name 
    self.unique = kw.pop('unique', False)
    self.kwargs = kw
```

Now in `__init__` of the `Index` they only check the `unique`. I think to generate fulltext index you have to use `DDL` manipulation functionality of sqlalchemy.

Comment: example of DDL: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/schema.html?highlight=ddl#sqlalchemy.schema.DDL